# How to find the impulse response of a filter, given the difference equation?

Tags: filters, finite-impulse-response

What is the impulse response of the system:
$$
y[n]= \frac{16}{26T} \left(-\frac{1}{16} x[n]  + x[n-2] - x[n-4] + \frac{1}{16} x[n-6] \right)?
$$

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, to get impulse response `h[n]`, assume the impulse signal given as:

```
x[0] = 1, else x[n] = 0, n <> 0.
```

Then

```
y[0] = 16/26T*(-1/16 + 0 - 0 + 0/16) = -16/(26T*16)
y[1] = 16/26T*(-0/16 + 0 - 0 + 0/16) = 0
y[2] = 16/26T*(-0/16 + 1 - 0 + 0/16) = 16/26T
y[3] = 16/26T*(-0/16 + 0 - 0 + 0/16) = 0
y[4] = 16/26T*(-0/16 + 0 - 1 + 0/16) = -16/26T
y[5] = 16/26T*(-0/16 + 0 - 0 + 0/16) = 0
y[6] = 16/26T*(-0/16 + 0 - 0 + 1/16) = 16/(26T*16)
y[7] = 0
y[8] = 0
...
```

so impulse response

```
h[n] = -16/(26T*16)*i[n-0] + 16/26T[n-2] - 16/26T[n-4] + 16/(26T*16)[n-6]
```

where `i[n]` is impulse with amplitude 1 at discrete time 0.

[Check more here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_impulse_response)

BTW: it is interesting fact, that impulse response of FIR filter contains its coefficients with proper time delays.

Answer (score 1):

First, remember that the impulse response is literally "the response of a system to an impulse." 
If the input is an impulse ($x[n] = \delta[n]$), then the output is the impulse response ($y[n] = h[n]$).

So if you had the system 
$$
y[n] = x[n] + 2x[n-1]
$$
Then the impulse response is 
$$
h[n] = \delta[n] + 2\delta[n-1]
$$
which is sometimes written as a vector, like $h[n] = [1,2]$ for $n=0,1$.

As a side note that does not apply to your specific question, this method does not give a very satisfying answer for recursive equations. If your system were
$$
y[n] = 0.9y[n-1] + x[n]
$$
then you get 
$$
h[n] = 0.9h[n-1] + \delta[n]
$$
so that the impulse response is defined in a recursive way. You would need another approach to get the impulse response defined by a non-recursive equation.